# PHP daylight saving wrong timezone

Tags: php, timezone, timezone-offset

This script should print

```
3600
7200
```

but it prints

```
3600
3600
```

Why? As far as I know php supports daylight saving.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Berlin");

$date1 = new DateTime();
$date1->setDate(2019,1,1); // winter time
$date1->setTime(0,0,0,0);

$date2 = new DateTime();
$date2->setDate(2019,6,1); // summer time
$date2->setTime(0,0,0,0);

$ref = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
echo $date1->getTimeZone()->getOffset($ref);
echo "\n";
echo $date2->getTimeZone()->getOffset($ref);
echo "\n";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `$ref` variable is representing "now".  In the `echo` statements, you pass `$ref` to `getOffset`, so it is getting the current offset as of now. Instead, pass `$date1` or `$date2`.

```
echo $date1->getTimeZone()->getOffset($date1);
echo "\n";
echo $date2->getTimeZone()->getOffset($date2);
echo "\n";
```

Or better yet, just call `getOffset()` directly:

```
echo $date1->getOffset();
echo "\n";
echo $date2->getOffset();
echo "\n";
```

Comment: Thank you it works. Can you explain why your first snippet works? Because the offset of a time zone relative to itself should always be zero. I don't understand why my code is not working.

Comment: @somega Your are passing as argument of getOffset($ref), and this variable refers to object instantiate by calling new DateTime(). However he is passing $date1 and $date2, that are dates that you set with setDate() method.

Comment: `getTimeZone()` gives back the `DateTimeZone` object assigned to the `DateTime`. 
 In this case, it's the one representing `Europe/Berlin`.  The offset is the offset *relative to UTC* for `Europe/Berlin` at the date/time given.  It's not the offset relative to itself.  You would get the same result by calling `new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin')->getOffset($date1)`.